# I need to change "Continue Reading " to "Read more" How to do?

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, com-content

[image]

HI.
I need to change "Continue Reading " to "Read more"  How to do?
*Joomla 3.4.5
Thk.

Comment: Is this "Continue reading" showing in article or something else? Please explain

Answer (score 3):

You can override the "Read more" text in the admin section.

In the "Extensions" menu, choose the Language menu item.

Then choose "overrides" and click "new".

You can search for the constant you want to override in that screen.

Help is available on that page and it links to: https://help.joomla.org/proxy/index.php?option=com_help&keyref=Help34:Extensions_Language_Manager_Overrides_Edit

Comment: I'm find not found "Continue Reading"

Comment: When searching, search by "value" to find where "Continue Reading" is used.

Comment: Also, it is possible that the "continue reading" text is part of a module or component that you installed, where you'll need to check with the template or configuration for that module or component.

Comment: about Blog(Continue Reading) where root on directory?

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?  There are so many places that could be depending on what and how you've set your site up.  Also, if you have access to the linux shell root of the site, you could grep -r 'Continue Reading' . to find where that value is set.

Comment: Link => http://405565033.student.yru.ac.th/panfolios/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=14&Itemid=235

Comment: Three things... search for the variable "READ MORE", as that is the actual variable name that Joomla uses.  Second, it looks like you're using a zootheme named avion.  You can contact their support for direct help.  Third, you'll be able find that variable in the file system by typing the following at the shell promt in the root directory; grep -r 'Continue Reading' .

Answer (score 1):

When you create your articles you have a tab called **Options**,
from here, at the bottom, you can see the **Read More field** for your 
custom text.

Best Regards!